# How to pass a component as a parameter of another component in vue?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have three component (A, B and C) and I need to pass the component B or C as a property of component A, and the component B will add this component to its template, so in this case, I can pass any component.

Component A

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>header</h1>
    {{ component }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'A',
  props: {
    component: {
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Component B

```
<template>
  c
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'B',
};
</script>
```

Component C

```
<template>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'B',
};
</script>
```

So, if I pass the component B as a property of component A the result should be:

```
<h1>header</h1>
<span>this is the content</span>
```

but if I pass the component C as a property the result should be:

```
<h1>header</h1>
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

I tried creating a property in A component and passing but I received undefined:

```
<template>
   <A :component="component"></A>
</template>

...

props: {
  component: {
      template: '<B></B>',
    },
  },
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

**UPDATED:**

Finally I used the vue's slot.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you want with Vue's "Dynamic Components."   You can then pass the name of the component `B` or `C` as a prop to `A` and then use it in the following manner.

```
<template>
   <div> 
     <h1>header</h1>
     <component v-bind:is="dynamicComponent"></component>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
      props: ['dynamicComponent'],
   }
 </script>
```

The actual syntax is `<component v-bind:is="theComponentName"></component>`  or with shorthand v-bind `<component :is="theComponentName"></component>`

For more see the docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components